# matplotlib upper limits inverted

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` to make a scatter plot with upper and lower limits. I noticed that my lower limits are plotted with arrows pointing downwards instead of upwards and vice versa.

Any idea why is this the case?

Here is an example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [5, 6, 7, 8]
fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=0.1, lolims=True)
```

I could just switch them, but it does not feel right :p

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `ax.errorbar` with `ax.error`?

Comment: yes, thanks. I will fix that.

Comment: also, it's `lolims`, not `lolim`

Comment: fixed that one too. Thx!

Comment: In my opinion is a bug or a bad documented feature. I have 3 options: 1) wait until someone of the `matplotlib` developers shows up; 2) send a mail to the mailing list; 3) file an issue on [matplotlib github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib). If I have some time, I'll try to look better into errobar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an open issue : https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2452

From what I see, there is a fix proposed three months ago, but it has hasn't been accepted yet. Anyway, you can patch yourself the modified files, and wait for the next iteration of matplotlib.